# Get last 10 execution time of a query in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012

With this query I'm getting the top 10 slow queries in Sql Server.

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    SUBSTRING(qt.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1, 
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.text) 
                                   ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
      END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1), 
    qs.execution_count, 
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.min_logical_reads, qs.max_logical_reads,
    qs.total_elapsed_time, qs.last_elapsed_time,
    qs.min_elapsed_time, qs.max_elapsed_time,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
WHERE 
    qt.encrypted = 0
ORDER BY 
    qs.total_logical_reads DESC
```

What I want to do is finding each queries last 10 execution time. 
Or an average execution period in a day makes me glad.

Answer (score 0):

You can create snapshots of your database procedure executions at certain period of time and then you can compare them. Use the sql in order to insert into table every snapshot.

```
    SELECT 
         getDAte() as SnapshotDate,
         s.database_id,
       s.[plan_handle],
       s.[object_id],
       s.last_execution_time,
       s.execution_count,
       s.total_worker_time,
       s.last_worker_time,
       s.min_worker_time,
       s.max_worker_time,
       s.total_physical_reads,
       s.last_physical_reads,
       s.min_physical_reads,
       s.max_physical_reads,
       s.total_logical_writes,
       s.last_logical_writes,
       s.min_logical_writes,
       s.max_logical_writes,
       s.total_logical_reads,
       s.last_logical_reads,
       s.min_logical_reads,
       s.max_logical_reads,
       s.total_elapsed_time,
       s.last_elapsed_time,
       s.min_elapsed_time,
       s.max_elapsed_time  

FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS s 
WHERE s.database_id NOT IN
                           (
                             DB_ID('master'),
                             DB_ID(N'tempdb'),
                             DB_ID(N'model'), DB_ID(N'msdb'),
                             32767 -- RESOURCE db

                         ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that is running slowly and why, check [Standard reports in SSMS](http://jasonbrimhall.info/2011/03/16/sql-server-standard-reports-winforms/).